# Retrieve mouse coordinate in matplotlib from image plot (not figure)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to print out the mouse coordinate upon clicking on the displayed image. It is not a graph figure.

After looking through all online forum, I discovered they are all made for a graph figure and not displayed images. I'm surprised I couldn't find even one example.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

# The usual way which I found online
fig = plt.figure() 
ax = fig.add_subplot(111) 
ax.plot(np.random.rand(10)) 

def onclick(event): 
     print("button=%d, x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f" %( 
         event.button, event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata)) 

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick) 

# What I currently Have
img = mpimg.imread("my_img.jpg")
plt.imshow(img)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Are you looking to find the mouse coordinate relative to your screen or image?

Comment: If you are looking to get coordinates from image you can also try the trackpy module that does this.

Comment: Axios, it is relative to the image. It is actually displayed on the bottom right corner, I just need to have in my python code.

Answer (score 2):

Matplot uses the same methods to display plot or image. You have to only find `figure` for displayed image.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

def onclick(event): 
    print("button=%d, x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f" % ( 
         event.button, event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata)) 

img = mpimg.imread("image.jpg")
ax = plt.imshow(img)
fig = ax.get_figure()
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick) 

plt.show()
```

---

Instead of `mpimg.imread()` you can use `plt.imread()`